# SQL character separated field to separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

We have a database with data from our ERP, which is not so flexible, and we are using that data to create reports in SSRS.
Now I have a price column for our articles/products which is formatted very bad by the ERP designers. The data is stored with a "type"-identifier, the ones that are causing trouble are:

```
1 and 5: scaled ==> 2 lines/rows separated by ASCII char(9) and ASCII char(13) followed by char(10) for the second line.
```

As an example, this is one field:

```
11  999999999
16,9    11,154
This is another example:
99  1049    999999999
2   1,32    0,8
```

Row 1 is always QP, row 2 is always SP. I've edited this to be more clear, cause the previous representation was causing confusion.
The number of char(9)-columns is variable, but the maximum amount is 3, so some can be 2.
I'm having trouble separating the second and sometimes third column and separating the second 'row' into columns.
The new table should be formatted like this.

```
ID  identifier  QP1 SP1 QP2 SP2 QP3 SP3

The fields which are used are 'id', 'SPtype' ==>identifier, 'vk1'==>contains the prizes; and the table is 'DW_D_PRODUCT'.
```

Could somebody provide me an efficient T-SQL. To handle this problem.
The could should preferable be a stored procedure, cause it should run every night to update the prizes in the tables.

Comment: Please edit this to a readable text.

Comment: please give clear post

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not very clear what is the expected output I want to share with you a function that I use when I have to deal with records as fields:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString] 
(   
  @Values nvarchar(max),
  @ValueSeparator nvarchar(5)
)
RETURNS @Result TABLE
(
  Ord int,
  Value nvarchar(100) -- can be adjusted
) 
AS
BEGIN
  ;with ValuesToXML as
  (
    select CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(@Values, @ValueSeparator, '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML) as 'Values'
  ),
  ValuesToList as 
  (
    select  x.i.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int') as 'Ord',
            x.i.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS 'Value' -- can be adjusted
    from    ValuesToXML
            CROSS APPLY 
            [Values].nodes('//i') x(i)
  )
  INSERT INTO @Result (Ord,Value) select * from ValuesToList;

  return;
END
```

Although it's compact the body is not really straight forward to understand.
It converts a `nvarchar` to a table using `XML`.
What's really powerful about this table valued `function` it's... the fact that it can be used as a table in `SELECT` statements, of course.

Here are some examples of usage. 
1) Simple call:

```
select * from dbo.SplitString('value1;value2;value3;value4', ';')
```

Result:

```
Ord   Value
  1   value1
  2   value2
  3   value3
  4   value4
```

2) On your data:

```
;with records as
(
    select * from
    (
        values  (1, '11  999999999 ==> QP' + char(9) + char(13) + '16,9    11,154 ==>SP'),
                (2, '99  1049    999999999 ==>QP' + char(9) + char(13) + '2   1,32    0,8 ==>SP')
    ) as v(id, txt)
),
subrecords1 as
(
    select   r.id
            ,s.ord as ord1
            ,s.value as value
    from    records r
            cross apply
            dbo.SplitString(r.txt, char(9) + char(13)) s
),
subrecords2 as
(
    select   r.id
            ,r.ord1
            ,s.ord as ord2
            ,s.value as value
    from    subrecords1 r
            cross apply
            dbo.SplitString(r.value, '==>') s
),
subrecords3 as
(
    select   r.id
            ,r.ord1
            ,r.ord2
            ,s.ord as ord3
            ,s.ord3c as ord3c   
            ,s.value as value
    from    subrecords2 r
            cross apply
            ( 
                select   ord 
                        ,row_number() over (order by ord) as ord3c -- consecutive ord3
                        ,ltrim(rtrim(value)) as value
                from    dbo.SplitString(r.value, ' ')
                where   value != '' --this will cause ord3 not to be consecutive
            )s
)
select * from subrecords3
```

Result:

```
id  ord1  ord2  ord3  ord3c  value
 1     1     1     1      1  11
 1     1     1     3      2  999999999
 1     1     2     2      1  QP
 1     2     1     1      1  16,9
 1     2     1     5      2  11,154
 1     2     2     1      1  SP
 2     1     1     1      1  99
 2     1     1     3      2  1049
 2     1     1     7      3  999999999
 2     1     2     1      1  QP
 2     2     1     1      1  2
 2     2     1     4      2  1,32
 2     2     1     8      3  0,8
 2     2     2     1      1  SP
```

Does this mean anything for you? 
You can break the query above and see what each CTE returns. 
Here are some hints:

- `id` is the id of the original record
- records with `ord1 = 1` and `ord2 = 2` are always `'QP'`
- records with `ord1 = ord2 = 1` are the values for `QP`
- records with `ord1 = ord2 = 2` are always `'SP'`
- records with `ord1 = 2` and `ord2 = 1` are the values for `SP`

Because in `subrecords3` CTE we have some filtering the ord3 will not have consecutive values. That's the reason we add `ord3c` column.

Now the `subrecords3` can be further joined with itself based on `id, ord1, ord2, ord3c` in order to map SP values with QP values.

Good luck!